# Android Service which run every hour to get data from Webservice and updates localStorage webview chromeclinet

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, webview, local-storage, webchromeclient

In my Android App, I'm retrieving data from `localStorage` and showing in `listview`. Now I want it to get the updated data from the webservice even when app is closed.

I am using `webchromeclient`. I have tried with services but it starts only with app and I am not able to interact with `localStorage` when app is closed or destroyed and I tried to trigger service on alarm

code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
WakefulIntentService.acquireStaticLock(context);
    context.startService(new Intent(context, AppService.class));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example if i need run my service every 3 second use below code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LockService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 3*1000, pintent);
```

end need BroadcastReceiver for when phone reboot, like follow code:

```
public class MyScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 60;

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60);

    service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);

  }
}
```

and help class:

```
public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, LocalWordService.class);
    context.startService(service);
  }
}
```

and require permission

and define service and BroadcastReceiver on manifest

Comment: Hi. thanks for the answer. I'm the UI designer for this app. I think you misunderstood the question or OP didn't explained it clearly. He wanted to store the json data to localstorage even when app is not opened in an hourly basis. he is not getting how to store data through android service as well.